# New bean is injected even when not calling getBean from spring context

Tags: java, spring

I have a bean declared in by config file as:

```
@Bean
@Lazy
@Scope("prototype")
public SomeClass someClass()
{
   return new SomeClass();
}
```

Then inside my test class I have the following code:

```
@Autowired
private SomeClass someClass;

@Before
public void setUp()
{
   xyzObject.someMethod(someClass);
}
```

My question here is inside my `setUp()` method I am just referencing the autowired `SomeClass` bean but not getting it from the spring context using `getBean()`, but still it is creating a new bean everytime the `setUp()` is running before a test. Why is this happening? Does prototype scope means a new bean gets created whenever the bean's reference is used anywhere in the code? I haven't seen anything specified like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the essence of Inversion of Control. Because you injected it into another bean, every time you instantiate another bean your injected bean would be created and provided by spring as part of instantiation of your containing bean. You don't need to call `getBean()` here. However if in some place you just need an instance of your `SomeClass` bean you may call `getBean()` to tell your spring environment to give you that bean to you. However, It is better to avoid such practice and rely on injection. Or create a Factory that can provide you such Bean (Still relaying on spring though) That would make your code not aware of Spring which is IMHO is more ellegant

Comment: I injected SomeClass into my test class, did you mean another bean as my test class? In that case it is instantiated only once, so the injected SomeClass should be provided by the spring only once.

Comment: You are correct. But each time you run your test your test class gets newly created (for each test). In other words setUp method is run once per lifetime of your test class and thus your SomeClass indeed gets created only once per each creation of your testclass. If you want to check it add a default constructor to your testclass and add some print out in your constructor. You will see that the Someclass only instantiated each time once after your test constructor runs.